Launch embedded Citrix VDA in WPF
I am exploring the idea to have a VDA embedded in our full screen WPF app, being used on touchscreen and and having custom input method (custom on-screen keyboard).
So far, I've identified the following

Launch of a Citrix VDA could be done programmatically using Unified Workspace API, similar to Citrix(R) Unified Workspace API - Native Client sample
The launched process could be configured as subprocess of the wpf app and have it's window headers removed using Windows APIs.
The launched process could be partially overlayed over the parent app, giving the feeling that the VDA is inside our app.

and now the question comes:
Is there a way to identify user action done in a VDA launched, more especially, the event when user clicks on a textbox or similar?
I would need this in order to trigger our custom On Screen Keyboard...
As far as I know, Citrix VDA's basically are views of a remote application, being also rendered remotely.
At this point did not found any Citrix SDK/API that would provide the above functionality.
Any thoughts?
Note: all the above thoughts are relying on theoretical research, I do not have a Citrix Environment available...
